# Spring Web Flow transitions not triggered

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow-2

I am using Spring Web Flow 2 and am having a basic problem getting my transitions to appropriately fire. I have done a lot of searching on the internet and have been unable to find an in-depth explanation of how transitions are triggered from the view side. I have two states: enterBookingDetails and reviewBooking. EnterBookingDetails is working fine - the page is loading and on submit event, reviewBooking is loaded. My problem is, I can't get any of the transitions from reviewBooking to work. Here is what I have:

booking-flow.xml:

```
<var name="bookingForm" class="com.mypackage.CarBookingForm"/>

<view-state id="enterBookingDetails" model="bookingForm">
    <transition on="submit" to="reviewBooking" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="reviewBooking" model="bookingForm">
    <transition on="confirm" to="bookingConfirmed" />
    <transition on="revise" to="enterBookingDetails" />
    <transition on="cancel" to="bookingCancelled" />
</view-state>

<end-state id="bookingConfirmed" />

<end-state id="bookingCancelled" />
```

enterBookingDetails.jsp (excerpt):

```
<form:form modelAttribute="bookingForm">
    Pickup: <form:input path="pickUpLocation"/><br />
    Dropoff: <form:input path="dropOffLocation"/><br />
    <input type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" value="Confirm"/>
    <input type="submit" name="_eventId_other" value="Other"/>
</form:form>
```

reviewBooking.jsp (excerpt):

```
Pickup Loc: ${bookingForm.pickUpLocation}<br />
Dropoff Loc: ${bookingForm.dropOffLocation}<br />

<form>
    <input type="submit" name="_eventId_confirm" value="Confirm" />
    <input type="submit" name="_eventId_revise" value="Revise" />
    <button type="submit" name="_eventId_cancel">Cancel</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
</form>
```

When any of the buttons are clicked on "reviewBooking", the user is taken back to "enterBookingDetails" with none of the form data populated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you ever get this working, I appear to have the same problem.

Comment: Please see the answer I posted with the resolution of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out the problem. All of the transitions were actually firing. The issue was that the two problematic transitions went to end states, and I didn't realize that by default those were ending the flow and then redirecting back to the first page.