# Spring web flow not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, cas, spring-webflow-2

I have defined a logout flow as :

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow.xsd">

<view-state id="casLogoutPopup" view="casLogoutApplicationsPopup_new"> 
    <transition on="ok" to="test" />
    <transition on="cancel" to="test2" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="test" view="casLogoutView" />
<view-state id="test2" view="casLoginView" />
```

And this is my jsp file "**casLogoutApplicationsPopup_new.jsp**" which is displayed when accessing logout from the browser.

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
    <input class="btn_submit" type="submit" name="_eventId_ok" accesskey="o" value="OK" />
    <input class="btn_submit" type="submit" style="float: right" name="_eventId_cancel" accesskey="c" value="CANCEL"/>
</form>
```

The problem is I am not able to initiate "test" web flow on click of OK/CANCEL button.

Comment: This is a possibly a duplicate question. Check out the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227837/spring-web-flow-transitions-not-triggered

Comment: No,In that flow both transitions went to end states but here I am not even able to capture click event

Comment: You're not using the Spring `form:form` and `form:input` tags?

Answer (score 0):

try with the execution url in the action attribute:

```
<form action="${flowExecutionUrl}">
    <input class="btn_submit" type="submit" name="_eventId_ok" accesskey="o" value="OK" />
    <input class="btn_submit" type="submit" style="float: right" name="_eventId_cancel" accesskey="c" value="CANCEL"/>
</form>
```